# Problems in IE7 with li tags nested in nav tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, html-lists, internet-explorer-6, nav

It seems very trendy these days to us `<li>` tags for navigation purposes without nesting them inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>`. But I have been having rendering problems in IE7 and below (no surprise there) when nesting the `<li>` tag directly inside an HTML5 `<nav>` tag.

The following example does some funny things:

```
<nav class="nav1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</nav>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
<nav class="nav2">
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</nav>
```

[Demo of code above](http://jsbin.com/ubajon/3/) including CSS

Using IETester and the debugging tool, if you analyse the DOM you will see that it looks like IE duplicates some `<li>` tags and tries to pull them together, even though they are separated by a `<p>` tag.

[image]

This yields strange results (visually) when you have multiple `<nav>` `<li>` combos throughout your page.

Has anybody else experienced this and can they provide a solution to fix it? Am I going to have to include a `<ul>` tag and risk looking untrendy? :)

Comment: You're supporting IE7 and you're worried about being trendy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even by HTML5 rules, an [`li` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) is allowed only as a child of `ul`, `ol`, or `menu`. All bets are off if you violate this, and it’s pointless to do so. So just stop doing so and wrap `li` elements inside `ul` (which you can wrap inside `nav` if you like, but there is no tangible gain from that).

Comment: Thanks for that... I will take your advice ;)